# Is the bicategory of sets and relations a Markov category?

Tags: pr.probability, ct.category-theory

I am reading Patterson's paper *[Knowledge representation in bicategories of relations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00526)*.  It looks like it has many of the properties of the Markov categories which Fritz has been detailing in *[A synthetic approach to Markov kernels, conditional independence and theorems on sufficient statistics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07021)*.  Is the bicategory of sets and relations actually a Markov category?

[Edit]
Someone has pointed out that I may be asking about the bicategory version of Markov categories. So, the question is, is the bicategory Rel a Markov bicategory.

Comment: If I read the Fritz link, I read that a Markov category is a category endowed with some additional structure (symmetric monoidal  + ...). So given a category, the question "is this a Markov category" doesn't make sense (as "is this topological space a category?" is senseless). The closest I could imagine is whether it admits such a structure (which might be or not be unique). Is it the desired meaning of the question.

Comment: @YCor that is the standard interpretation of what the question is asking, it's not a type mismatch, past phrasing the answer as "yes, using the [blah] monoidal structure" (if this is the case).

Comment: Do you mean a bicategorical version of Markov category? Or a truncation of Rel to a 1-category? And if the first, do you mean the definition of $\mathbf{Rel}$ as a 2-category at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel#definition ?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for the questions.  I am interested to know if the 2-category, along with it's 2-morphisms is Markov, and so I guess I am wondering about the bicatecory version of Markov category.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Thankfully, $\mathbf{Rel}$ is a (1,2)-category (it is poset-enriched, not category-enriched, so questions of coherence for a 2-categorical version of a Markov category will not be so scary.

Comment: I have no answer to this question because I don't know what a Markov 2-category would be, but I'm interested in working on this problem.